# Issue with File Not Found

Tags: python, filenotfoundexception

I'm having an issue just drawing from a file which I don't think I've had an issue with before. I'm not sure if it's because I switched from PyCharm to IDLE

Here is my current code:

```
import time
import os

keep_running = True
last_time = 0
file = os.path.abspath(r'C:\Users\AUser\Desktop\test.txt')
current_time = os.path.getmtime(file)

print(file)
```

Here is the output I'm getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/AUser/Desktop/Scripts/FileAlert.py", line 9, in <module>
    current_time = os.path.getmtime(file)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\genericpath.py", line 55, in getmtime
    return os.stat(filename).st_mtime
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Users\\AUser\\Desktop\\test.txt'
```

If I remove 'r' from the file path, I get a unicode error instead. The file is in a different directory from the script so I'm not sure what the issue is. This is happening with Python 3.9 on a Windows 10 machine.

Comment: My suggestion is to use / instead of \.
And verify you have the path set properly.

Comment: Does that file exist? It seems it does not. You could try `import os` and then `os.listdir('C:\\Users\\AUser\\Desktop')` to get the directory list.

Comment: @EllisThompson - I don't think it will make a difference. `C:\\Users\\AUser\\Desktop\\test.txt` doesn't exist.

Comment: @tdelaney so the error is correct then? If the file doesn't exist then this is the expected output.

Comment: @EllisThompson - Right. The error message shows the path using python's technique of double backslash escaping to a  single backslash. Undoing that, the message says that `C:\Users\AUser\Desktop\test.txt` doesn't exist. The poster should take that to heart!

Comment: @tdelaney - This helped me find and fix the issue actually, the issue is I had it literally as test.txt, which was saved as 'test.txt.txt' So simple user error, my bad. Thank you for the help.

Comment: that's a common problem on Windows which likes to hide file extensions from you. I had to terminate a contract because the customer demanded that the program I produced not have a ".exe" on the end.

Comment: You have to create test.txt file on desktop first. You dont have text file that why giving error. Just try to make file same name used in puthon path then try

Answer (score 0):

In this case the issue is the file being searched for was technically named 'test.txt.txt'.

Using this suggestion helped me to locate this error on my end:

Does that file exist? It seems it does not. You could try import os and then os.listdir('C:\Users\AUser\Desktop') to get the directory list. from user @tdelaney